# Rule to build solution before check-in in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

Is it possible to use StyleCop to enforce these two rules?

1. Get latest version before check in
2. Build solution with a
   specific configuration before check in

Any other suggestions besides StyleCop are welcomed. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

No. [Stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) is *an open source static code analysis tool from Microsoft that checks C# code for conformance to StyleCop's recommended coding styles and a subset of Microsoft's .NET Framework Design Guidelines.*
<sub>([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop))</sub>

To enforce the getting of the latest version before checking in, you could use a [custom TFS policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx). This seems to have been successful for [other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324498/how-to-ensure-that-tfs-clients-has-the-latest-version-of-a-custom-check-in-polic).

To check that a particular solution builds before checking in, you could use a [Gated Check-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx) for that solution. The code won't be committed if that solution (and it's tests do not pass).